# How to pull private git repo using chef from gitolite

Tags: git, chef-infra

I am new to using chef.
I am able to clone/pull a github repository using the following code on my recipe

```
git "/var/www/hello_app" do
  repository "git://github.com/MyUser/MyProject.git"
  reference "master"
  action "sync"
  user "gituser"
end
```

I am trying to pull/clone my files from a private git repository managed my gitolite which means that authentication relies on sshd. 
I already have my id_rsa private key installed through a data_bag on gituser's .ssh/id_rsa file , the user who is pulling/cloning the private repo. Pulling/cloning the repository manually works.

The command I execute is

```
git clone gitoliteuser@myserver:MyProject.gr
```

How should I modify my recipe so I can pull my private repository ?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :) It looks like you commented indicating Graham posted the correct answer - can you mark it as correct please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important part of the resource is the `repository` value.  To use your gitolite repo, change the value to the one shown in your question:

```
git "/var/www/hello_app" do
  repository "gitoliteuser@myserver:MyProject.gr"
  reference "master"
  action "sync"
  user "gituser"
end
```

More details about using the git resource can be found on the opscode site here : http://docs.opscode.com/resource_git.html

Comment: Thank you.I figured it out eventually but I have now seen you reply. So I would like to thank you just for posting.

Comment: If you think the answer was useful, please can you accept it, so that others can benefit?  Cheers