# Troubles Cloning a Chef Private Repo Using Test Kitchen

Tags: git, chef-infra, gitolite, cookbook, test-kitchen

I am having trouble trying to clone a private git repository from gitolite. I am installing git 2.8.1 and using Chef 12.9. I am trying to create an SSH wrapper that the chef git resource can use to authenticate into my repository.

```
....
file "/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh" do
  content "#!/bin/sh\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -i #{/tmp/key.pem} \"$@\""
  user "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0700"
  action :create
end
git "/home/some_repo" do
  repository "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git"
  revision "1.0.0"
  user "root"
  group "root"
  ssh_wrapper "/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh"
  action :sync
end
....
```

I get the following error when trying to sync to the git repo using test kitchen.

```
================================================================================
           Error executing action `sync` on resource 'git[/home/some_repo]'
           ===========================================================================    =====

           Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
           ------------------------------------
           Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
           ---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*" ----
           STDOUT:
           STDERR: Host key verification failed.
           fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

           Please make sure you have the correct access rights
           and the repository exists.
           ---- End output of git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*" ----
           Ran git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*" returned 128

           Resource Declaration:
           ---------------------
           # In /tmp/kitchen/cookbooks/version_control/definitions/some_git_repo.rb

            33:   git "/home/some_repo" do
            34:     repository "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git"
            35:     revision "1.0.0"
            36:     user "root"
            37:     group "root"
            38:     ssh_wrapper "/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh"
            39:     action :sync
            40:   end
            41:   # Remote the SSH private key

           Compiled Resource:
           ------------------
           # Declared in /tmp/kitchen/cookbooks/version_control/definitions/some_git_repo.rb:33:in `block in from_file'

           git("/home/some_repo") do
             params {:owner=>"root", :group=>"root", :mode=>"700", :revision=>"1.0.2", :path=>"/home/", :name=>"some_repo"}
             action [:sync]
             retries 0
             retry_delay 2
             default_guard_interpreter :default
             destination "/home/some_repo"
             enable_checkout true
             revision "1.0.0"
             remote "origin"
             ssh_wrapper "/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh"
             checkout_branch "deploy"
             declared_type :git
             cookbook_name :version_control
             recipe_name "test"
             repository "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git"
             user "root"
             group "root"
           end

           Platform:
           ---------
           x86_64-linux


       Running handlers:
       [2016-05-02T21:27:02+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
       Running handlers complete
       [2016-05-02T21:27:02+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
       Chef Client failed. 22 resources updated in 02 minutes 10 seconds
       [2016-05-02T21:27:02+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /tmp/kitchen/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
       [2016-05-02T21:27:02+00:00] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
       [2016-05-02T21:27:02+00:00] ERROR: git[/home/some_repo] (version_control::test line 33) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '128'
       ---- Begin output of git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*" ----
       STDOUT:
       STDERR: Host key verification failed.
       fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

       Please make sure you have the correct access rights
       and the repository exists.
       ---- End output of git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_company.git" "1.0.0*" ----
       Ran git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*" returned 128
       [2016-05-02T21:27:02+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
>>>>>> Converge failed on instance <test-add-some-repo-ubuntu-1404>.
>>>>>> Please see .kitchen/logs/test-add-some-repo-ubuntu-1404.log for more details
>>>>>> ------Exception-------
>>>>>> Class: Kitchen::ActionFailed
>>>>>> Message: SSH exited (1) for command: [sh -c '

sudo -E /opt/chef/bin/chef-solo --config /tmp/kitchen/solo.rb --log_level auto --force-formatter --no-color --json-attributes /tmp/kitchen/dna.json
']
>>>>>> ----------------------
```

The documentation for the git resource says that the ssh_wrapper property sets the GIT_SSH environment variable. When I log into the vagrant virtual machine setup by test-kitchen, and run the following command ...

```
GIT_SSH=/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*"
```

... I am able to gain access to the repository.

I have tried the solutions in a few stack overflow posts with no success.
[Chef git cookbook: how to fix permission denied while cloning private repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31496405/chef-git-cookbook-how-to-fix-permission-denied-while-cloning-private-repo), [How to pull private git repo using chef from gitolite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18713946/how-to-pull-private-git-repo-using-chef-from-gitolite), [Chef deploy_resource private repo, ssh deploy keys and ssh_wrapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18388722/chef-deploy-resource-private-repo-ssh-deploy-keys-and-ssh-wrapper), [git error while deploying through chef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24277978/git-error-while-deploying-through-chef)

I have also tried running ...

```
GIT_SSH=/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh git ls-remote "git@cookbooks.somecompany.com:some_repo.git" "1.0.0*"
```

... using the bash and execute resource.

I don't understand why I am unable to clone this repository. It seems like I am missing something basic here, but I don't really know what. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SSH wrapper needs to disable host key verification or you need to pre-populate the known_hosts file. Check out the application_git cookbook which takes care of all this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your help. For those interested, I updated my ssh_wrapper file to contain the following. 

file "/tmp/ssh_wrapper.sh" do
  content "#!/bin/sh\nexec /usr/bin/ssh -i #{/tmp/key.pem} -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \"$@\""
  user "root"
  group "root"
  mode "0700"
  action :create
end